# RealityKit – Convert CGPoint to a SIMD<Float>

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am using RealityKit and when I tap on the screen, I just want to add a box on that place where I tapped. It can be on the middle of the screen or anywhere. I will adjust Z axis so the object is placed 1 meter away from me. But I am having a hard time converting CGPoint to relevant RealityKit coordinates.

```
@objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
    guard let view = view else { return }
        
    let location = recognizer.location(in: view)
        
    // location to SIMD3<Float> so I can create an anchor    
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### Model on a detected plane

`CGPoint` is a XY-point on iPhone's screen, so there's no need to convert it to XYZ-point. If you need a 3D point on a detected plane for accomodating your model, all you have to do is to generate an object from `ARRaycastResult` (or `ARHitTestResult` in case you're using [ARKit+SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088307/place-multiple-scn-objects-in-touchesbegan-method/60225010#60225010)).

```
import RealityKit
import ARKit

var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

@objc func tappingScreen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let results: [ARRaycastResult] = arView.raycast(from: arView.center,
                                                allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                               alignment: .horizontal)

    if let result: ARRaycastResult = results.first {

        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.02))
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

### Model at camera's position

Creating a model exactly where ARCamera is located in the current frame is super easy:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.02))

    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: arView.cameraTransform.matrix)
    anchor.addChild(model)
    model.position.z = -0.5            // 50 cm offset
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
```

Also, you can multiply camera's transform by desired offset:

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.5         // 50 cm offset

// Multiplying camera matrix by offset matrix
let transform = simd_mul(arView.cameraTransform.matrix, translation)
model.transform.matrix = transform
```

### Additional info

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399910/where-is-the-camera-anchorentity-located/60416601#60416601) is also helpful.